# Finding the equation of the vector plane

Tags: vectors

The points P and Q have position vectors, relative to the origin O, given by
−−→
OP = 7i + 7j − 5k and
−−→
OQ = −5i + j + k

The mid-point of PQ is the point A. The plane  is perpendicular to the line PQ and passes through A
 Find the equation of , giving your answer in the form ax + by + cz = d

Alright, I firstly found the direction of the line PQ and multiplied the direction by (a b c ) which is normal of the plane and equate it to zero. 
My mind blocked now and I can't seem to get the normal of the plane. Can someone help?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I believe I just attempted a similar way. But I couldn't figure out the final answer. the final answer is 12x-6y+6z=48 I would appreciate your explanation

Comment: My doubt is I can't seem to get how would the direction vector of the line be the same value as the normal of the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec r_P$ and $\vec r_Q$ represent two vectors.

The vector from $P$ to $Q$ is $\vec N=\vec r_Q-\vec r_P$, which is normal to a plane.

The midpoint $\vec r_M$ between $P$ and $Q$ is $\vec r_M=\frac12 (\vec r_Q+\vec r_P)$.

The plane that passes through $\vec r_M$ and is normal to $\vec N$ can be expressed by

$$(\vec r-\vec r_M)\cdot \vec N=0$$

---

$\vec r_P=\hat i 7+\hat j 7-\hat i 5$

$\vec r_Q=-\hat i 5+\hat j 1-\hat i 1$

$\vec r_M=\frac12 (\vec r_P+\vec r_Q)=\hat i 1+\hat j 4-\hat i 2$

$\vec N=\vec r_Q-\vec r_P=-\hat i 12-\hat j 6+\hat i 6$

$\vec N\cdot (\vec r-\vec r_M)=(-12 x-6y+6z)-(-12-24-12)=0\Rightarrow 12x+6y-6z=48$

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just attempted a similar way. But I couldn't figure out the final answer.
the final answer is 
12x-6y+6z=48
I would appreciate your explanation

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.